# where do the temp table and variable_table to store,the physical disk or memory?

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables

I find that some people say that the temp table is stored on the physical disk because it is in the tempdb,then variable is in then memory(sometimes then physical disk depends on the counts of data).

so here comes the question one: where do they actually store！
question two: can I regard  the tempdb as a cache memory between the hard disk and memory?

Comment: Epic answer - https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16386/6171

Answer (score 0):

**temp tables** are **physically** created in the **tempdb** database.

**table variable** is created in the tempdb database **but not the memory (entirely)**.

Let me quote Microsoft's Support Document:

> A table variable is not a memory-only structure. Because a table
>   variable might hold more data than can fit in memory, it has to have a
>   place on disk to store data. Table variables are created in the tempdb
>   database similar to temporary tables. If memory is available, both
>   table variables and temporary tables are created and processed while
>   in memory (data cache).

Source: 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/305977/inf-frequently-asked-questions---sql-server-2000---table-variables

FYI, **CTE** are created **in memory** rather than tempdb database